# Query to list customers of a shop, with two different orders table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need sql help for a query:
I want to create a view to list customers of a shop. This is a select of users table that have made 1 or more reservation (table reservations) OR have made 1 or more order (table shop_orders).

```
-------------    --------------
| users:    |    | shops:     |
-------------    --------------
| id (PK)   |    | id (PK)    |
-------------    --------------

------------------    ----------------
| reservations:  |    | shops_orders:|
------------------    ----------------
| id (PK)        |    | id (PK)      |
| user_id (FK)   |    | user_id (FK) |
| shop_id (FK)   |    | shop_id (FK) |
------------------    ----------------
```

This is my starting point working ok:

```
SELECT u.*,
       r.shop_id,
      (SELECT count(*)
       FROM reservations r
       WHERE r.user_id = u.id) AS num_reservations,
      (SELECT count(*)
       FROM shop_orders so
       WHERE so.user_id = u.id) AS num_orders
FROM users u
INNER JOIN (SELECT r.user_id,
                   r.shop_id
            FROM reservations r
            UNION 
            SELECT so.user_id,
                   so.shop_id
            FROM shop_orders so) AS r ON u.id = r.user_id
GROUP BY u.id
```

All the queries to this view will be filtered by shop_id, to show only the customers of a concrete shop (is the shop administration area).

And only select customers that have reservations OR orders (num_reservations > 0 OR num_orders > 0)

The problem i find is the performance: 2 counts(*) from entire tables. And also an union between these 2 entire tables.

Do you think in a better alternative approach i could test?

Comment: what is sample data and desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT 
    u.*,
    r.shop_id,
    IFNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT r.id), 0) AS num_reservations,
    IFNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT o.id), 0) AS num_orders
FROM users u 
    LEFT JOIN reservarions r ON r.user_id = u.id
    LEFT JOIN shop_orders o ON o.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id
HAVING num_reservations + num_orders > 0
```

Another way, should be quicker:

```
SELECT 
    u.*,
    r.shop_id,
    IFNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT r.id), 0) AS num_reservations,
    IFNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT o.id), 0) AS num_orders
FROM users u 
    LEFT JOIN reservarions r ON r.user_id = u.id
    LEFT JOIN shop_orders o ON o.user_id = u.id
WHERE r.id IS NOT NULL OR o.id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY u.id
```

If you need to have it split by both users and stores they had used, do `GROUP BY u.id, r.shop_id`.

Comment: Is working, but also find performance problems: 2 x count(*) and a "having" that needs to operate in the whole users table...

Comment: Added another version, should be quicker.

Comment: @sashkello . . . If the OP wants to filter by `shop_id`, then that should be in the `group by` clause as well.  A user could presumably be a customer of more than one shop.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, yes, you are probably right - but this is not what I get from the sample query presented in the question. It's an easy fix though...